# Zortrax m200 skipping through menu options on it own and live print bed

Tags: troubleshooting

Out of the blue I’ve noticed my m200 has been skipping through menu options as if someone is pushing and scrolling the control knob randomly. Then getting a print off today I got several small electric shocks off the print bed through the spatula. Does anyone have experience of this or to I have a £1500 paperweight?

Answer (score 1):

## This sounds really concerning.

**Instantly** remove the machine from the power and check **EVERY** wire if it might be broken!

Check if your power supply is properly grounded!

Check if the connectors of the bed are undamaged!

Comment: I have done and nothing is obvious. I might try it on a different power loop. I’ve only been able to find one other case online of the bed acting live but not the menu skipping.

Comment: @JamesB the buttons might be borked. Or your grounding line might be damaged - or not connected to the house ground.